# Need to generate a large quantity of data using the rnorm function

Tags: r

I have a data frame for which each element in the data frame represents a mean value. The data frame looks like this:

```r
Mean_Data <- data.frame( Apple = runif(5), orange = runif(5), 
    Pear = runif(5), Banana = runif(5) )
```

I also have another data frame for which each element in this data frame represents an STD value correlating to each mean value in the Mean_Data data frame. This data frame looks like this:

```r
STD_Data <- data.frame( Red = runif(5), Blue = runif(5), 
   Green = runif(5), Yellow = runif(5) )
```

I want to write a function that uses `rnorm` to generate 50 random numbers using the mean and STD value obtained from each cell of the `Mean_Data` and `STD_Data` data frames.

For instance, I want to repeatedly use rnorm in the following fashion:

```r
rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[1,1], sd=STD_Data[1,1]) 
.
.
.
 rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[5,5], sd=STD_Data[5,5])
```

Thus, the output data frame will have 1,000 observations in total. I am assuming that I would need to write a function that uses the apply function, however, I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

This is what I have so far:

```r
Feat_Data <- function(Mean_Data, STD_Data) {   
   Feat_Data <-  as.data.frame(apply(Mean_Data, 2, rnorm(50, mean=, sd=)))  
   return(Feat_Data)
}
```

However, I do not know the proper syntax needed to fill in the mean and sd values of the `rnorm` function. I want to populate these parameter values with the values in each cell of the `Mean_Data` and `STD_Data` data frames.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "50 random numbers for each correlated mean". What is a "correlated mean"?

Comment: The data you provided do not contain anything named 'mean' or 'sd'. Please specify

Comment: You also provided two dataframes with 4 variables each. It is hard to imagine any iteration in a loop that would provide 25 combinations. If you want combinations of rows from different dataframes, I recommend you start from scratch and rethink your entire proposal.

Comment: I have edited my question based on the feedback provided.

Comment: If you use two VECTORS with 5 values each, you can simulate your data with 25 different combinations that would yiel 1250 values.

Why are you using 4x5 dataframes?

Comment: I don't get it either. 4 x 5 x 50 =  1000, (4*5)^2 * 50 = 20000 (all combinations).  Did you mean to include another column in each of your data frames?

Comment: Each column of the data frame represents a different group that I am observing, and each row represents an observed mean or STD value of that group, recorded daily. So imagine I am recording the mean weight and STD of the weight for 4 different groups of lab rats ,daily.  In total I want 50 days worth of observations of the mean and STD for each of the 4 groups. However, I cannot wait 50 days to gather all of the data.

Comment: Sorry Ben, my math was incorrect, I meant 1000 observations. I will correct that in my original post.

Comment: If 4x5x50=1000, Than why do you have two dataframes????

Comment: Hello Guedes, one data frame represents mean values, the other represents STD values. When using the rnonrm function you need to specify a mean and STD value. I want to get the mean value form the Mean_Data data frame and the STD value from the STD_Data data frame.

Comment: Your elements don`t match Like there is only bananas in one Df that is confusing

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be close to what you want

```r
library(tidyverse)

Mean_Data <- data.frame( Apple = runif(5), orange = runif(5), 
                         Pear = runif(5), Banana = runif(5) )


STD_Data <- data.frame( Red = runif(5), Blue = runif(5), 
                        Green = runif(5), Yellow = runif(5) )



temp_mean <- Mean_Data |> unname() |> as.matrix()
temp_std <- STD_Data |> unname() |> as.matrix()

temp_grid <- expand.grid(temp_mean,temp_std)

tidy_mean <- Mean_Data |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "names_mean",values_to = "values_mean") |> 
  arrange(names_mean)

tidy_sd <- STD_Data |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "names_sd",values_to = "values_sd") |> 
  arrange(names_sd)

tidy_simulation <- tidy_mean |> 
  bind_cols(tidy_sd)

tidy_simulation |> 
  mutate(generate = list(rnorm(50,mean = values_mean,sd = values_sd))) |> 
  unnest(generate)
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 5
#>    names_mean values_mean names_sd values_sd generate
#>    <chr>            <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439  -1.10  
#>  2 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   1.63  
#>  3 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   1.38  
#>  4 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   0.595 
#>  5 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   0.666 
#>  6 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439  -0.129 
#>  7 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   1.12  
#>  8 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   0.737 
#>  9 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   0.0333
#> 10 Apple            0.102 Blue         0.439   1.84  
#> # ... with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 21390)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
#> [5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.6     purrr_0.3.4    
#> [5] readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.2    ggplot2_3.3.3  
#> [9] tidyverse_1.3.1
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] tidyselect_1.1.1  xfun_0.23         haven_2.4.1       colorspace_2.0-1 
#>  [5] vctrs_0.3.8       generics_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1 yaml_2.2.1       
#>  [9] utf8_1.2.1        rlang_0.4.11      pillar_1.6.1      glue_1.4.2       
#> [13] withr_2.4.2       DBI_1.1.1         dbplyr_2.1.1      modelr_0.1.8     
#> [17] readxl_1.3.1      lifecycle_1.0.0   munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0     
#> [21] cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_1.0.0       evaluate_0.14     knitr_1.33       
#> [25] ps_1.6.0          fansi_0.5.0       highr_0.9         broom_0.7.6      
#> [29] Rcpp_1.0.6        backports_1.2.1   scales_1.1.1      jsonlite_1.7.2   
#> [33] fs_1.5.0          hms_1.1.0         digest_0.6.27     stringi_1.6.2    
#> [37] grid_4.1.0        cli_2.5.0         tools_4.1.0       magrittr_2.0.1   
#> [41] crayon_1.4.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    xml2_1.3.2       
#> [45] reprex_2.0.0      lubridate_1.7.10  assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_2.8    
#> [49] httr_1.4.2        rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.0          compiler_4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Map` approach -

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
  do.call(rbind, Map(function(p, q) rnorm(50, p, q), x, y))
}, Mean_Data, STD_Data)) -> result
```